# Can I receive a scoped dependency for a C# gRPC Client Interceptor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, grpc, grpc-dotnet

I am using a gRPC client inside a web API controller method to make a call out to a database and I want all of the calls made to add some common metadata in a transparent fashion. That is, I don't want to have to consciously add Metadata to every gRPC client call. A gRPC Interceptor seems perfect for this but to add that common metadata for each call, I need to resolve a scoped dependency that gives me the data I need to put in the gRPC call metadata.

Just as a similar example, in a .NET Core Middleware, I can resolve scoped dependencies by adding parameters to the `InvokeAsync(...)` method like this:

```cs
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, IMyScopedDependency myService)
    {
```

However, I am not sure if / how I can do the same thing with a gRPC Client Interceptor as those override methods from the base Interceptor class and I can't add arbitrary extra parameters to them.

Is there some clever way I am missing to inject a scoped lifetime dependency into the interceptor `public override AsyncUnaryCall<TResponse> AsyncUnaryCall<TRequest, TResponse>(...)` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by doing the following...

Registering my interceptor with a scoped lifetime:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<MyInterceptor>();
```

Registering my dependency with a scoped lifetime:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMyDependencyService, MyDependencyService>();
```

In my interceptor, I receive the scoped dependency via DI in the constructor:

```cs
internal class MyInterceptor: Interceptor
{
    private readonly IMyDependencyService _dependency;

    public MyInterceptor(IMyDependencyService dependency)
    {
        _dependency = dependency;
    }
```

I used [Grpc.Net.ClientFactory](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Net.ClientFactory/) to register my gRPC client with an interceptor using the `InterceptorScope.Client` lifetime option:

```cs
services.AddGrpcClient<MyGrpcClient>(o =>
{
    o.Address = new Uri("http://localhost:5000");
}).AddInterceptor(Grpc.Net.ClientFactory.InterceptorScope.Client, (sp) => sp.GetRequiredService<MyInterceptor>());
```

Finally, in my Web API controller, I receive the client via DI in the constructor and then I can use it in the controller methods:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly MyGrpcClient _client;
    private readonly ILogger<TestController> _logger;

    public TestController(MyGrpcClient client, ILogger<TestController> logger)
    {
        _client = client;
        _logger = logger;
    }
```